# Is it allowed to post syntax error problems?

Tags: support, questions, scope, close-reasons

It seems like some users use Stack Overflow as a debugging tool.

Example post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74619459/5089567 - the OP asked the question with an error and a few minutes after that added a comment with a different error.

How can posts like that be useful to anyone?

Can we close and delete posts like "I have a syntax error somewhere" immediately?

Comment: If you don't think it's useful, cast a downvote. If it fits one of the existing close votes without having to twist around like a crazy straw then cast a close vote. Manual deletion isn't often necessary if the previous two steps are followed.

Comment: Sometimes the cause of a syntax error is hard to diagnose, and a good answer will be revelatory to both the asker and future visitors. Things like a missing semicolon on a previous line, a missing closing brace, parenthesis, or closing quote, things of that nature will result in non-obvious syntax errors. I've had syntax error that have flummoxed me initially until I quickly found the answer on SO.

Comment: The mere *votes* on this post and the *votes* on @KevinB's answer make the answer to your question exceedingly clear.

Comment: @RobertBradley I don't quite understand the down votes really. I'm not sure what is wrong about my question

Comment: Personally, I think the downvotes were uncalled for, and I upvoted the question, but my point is that it shows people really don't like even *the idea* of posts being deleted for the reason you stated, and I would say it's because ultimately, we are here to help even total newbies, and if they are becoming lazy and coming here for every little thing, that's a problem that's better solved by just telling them to try and figure it out for themselves and include what they've tried. Because deletion is *very* serious, it shuts down opportunities to talk, and we know that must be *very* limited.

Comment: "It seems like some users use Stack Overflow as a debugging tool." - I would hesitate to say that a lot of users do that. We can't expect people to only post questions with the nobel intentions to help out many people. Secretly they're all asking for themselves and have to pretty print it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Syntax errors are valid questions if presented correctly.

The example you gave has a fairly poor title, and at first glance I don't think there's enough info in the question to solve it. We have a close reason for that.

Deletion isn't the correct action if the question is fixable (like this one) as that would make it *much* harder for the OP and others to correct the mistakes and turn it into a good question.

---

We don't have whole categories of questions that are just indiscriminately deleted. Instead, we have close reasons, upvotes/downvotes, and the roomba. There is no "This is a syntax error" close reason just like there isn't a "This is a homework question" reason or even a "this is a regex question" reason. Questions get closed based on the existing close reasons and usefulness is judged through upvotes and downvotes. If it isn't useful, the roomba cleans up the mess later. Deletion is for cases where the roomba can't clean up the mess and the information being presented is harmful or will attract further useless content.

Comment: Can syntax error question be useful for anyone except the author?

Comment: Yes, other people who run into the same error message can find that error message on SO. syntax errors and other types of errors alike. This is certainly an example of one that *wouldn't* be useful to anyone else, at least in its current state.

Comment: @Konrad depends on the question. A misplaced comma - probably not something that would be very useful for others. Questions that come up in basically the same form again and again such as [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896) or [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486) are some of *the* most frequent questions on JavaScript on Stack Overflow. Those are not specifically about SyntaxError itself but are deeply rooted in problems with syntax.

Comment: I think the question linked up top would be a useful question, if it asked about the new error in the comments. But it's also probably a [duplicate at that point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127130/console-is-throwing-unterminated-jsx-contents-error)

Comment: There is a difference between asking why a syntax doesn't work and pasting an error and waiting till someone will fix it. Allowing questions like that encourages new users to ask bad questions

Comment: That's not our problem to fix, at least not without a discussion on changing close reasons. If it doesn't fit a close reason, abusing the system to force it to fit isn't the way things work here

Comment: Let me put it another way. The majority of syntax error questions *will* be typos or will be lacking debugging details and should be closed as such. that doesn't mean *all* of them should be.

Comment: I just don't see any potential value for future users in "please fix the error for me" questions (not counting  questions about specific syntax). Wouldn't creating one post like "how to fix syntax errors"  and closing all of the others as duplicates of it a better option?

Comment: I mean, [this question right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127130/console-is-throwing-unterminated-jsx-contents-error) that i linked above is clearly a typo question that has proven to actually be useful to future visitors. Why would we delete it? just because it fits in the bucket? I'm not so sure it should even remain closed at this point.

Comment: @Konrad you're focusing on entirely the wrong thing: "*There is a difference between asking why a syntax doesn't work and pasting an error and waiting till someone will fix it*" a very large portion of questions are pasting an error (and maybe code) and waiting for somebody to fix it. I am highly confident the posters who do that are not interested one bit in whether their problem is due to syntax or something else. These sorts of questions are by and large closable. Usually unclear but many times they are simply duplicates.

Comment: You are right. The problem with the question I linked is not that it's about a syntax error but it's quality and lack of debugging details